# Integrating Microsoft Teams Embedded Share Button in React web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, microsoft-teams, share-button

Here is how I integrated Microsoft Teams Embedded Share Button in React:

**Step 1:** Add launcher.js script on my web app:

I took this script:

```
<script async defer src="https://teams.microsoft.com/share/launcher.js"></script>
```

And placed it in this useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');

  script.src = "https://teams.microsoft.com/share/launcher.js";
  script.async = true;
  script.defer = true;

  document.body.appendChild(script);

  return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  }
}, []);
```

***Step 2 :** Add an HTML element on my webapp with the teams-share-button class attribute and the link to share in the data-href attribute.*

I took this given code:

```
<div
  class="teams-share-button"
  data-href="https://<link-to-be-shared>">
</div>
```

And I adjusted it to React:

```
<div
  className="teams-share-button"
  data-href="https://<link-to-be-shared>">
</div>
```

**My problem is:**

The button is displayed in a popup module and my Microsoft Teams Embedded Share Button is disappearing after first rendering of the popup module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem.

The Microsoft Teams Embedded Share button is displayed in a popup module so I added the state in charge of displaying the popup modal, `showPopupModal`, as a second argument to the useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');

  script.src = "https://teams.microsoft.com/share/launcher.js";
  script.async = true;
  script.defer = true;

  document.body.appendChild(script);

  return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  }
}, [showPopupModal]);
```